# App freezing with no internet connectivity due to Urban Airship

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7, apple-push-notifications, urbanairship.com

I have used Urban Airship push notification in my app.
It works fine if internet connectivity is good. But when the internet connectivity is not there or it's slow, the app freezes on start.

Any ideas about it ?

Comment: Not sure if it helps.  But I remember vaguely looking into urban airship and the reason I never used it was because it requires internet connectivity on startup to verify your license since it charges based on usage.

Answer (score 0):

You did not say much about the structure of your app so I don't know if this will help. You should use Apple's Reachability to check for an internet connection. Doing that will allow you to branch to code which can inform the user to try again later due to no connection or do something else instead.

You can read up on Reachability [here](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html).

Comment: Thanks for replying. I figured out that my app is freezing due to 'reachability' itself.Though I still need to figure out the reason for it, but removing it solves the problem.